# Transformation of $L^2$ norm to another interval (failing in exercise)

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $\Phi(t)=a+\frac{1}{2}(1+t)(b-a)$. Then
$\Phi'(t)=\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Now let's transform the following $L^2$-norm from the interval $[-1,1]$ to the interval $[a,b]$, trough the substitution:
$$
\begin{align*}
x&=\Phi(t) 
\\
dx&=\Phi'(t)\,dt \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad dt
=\frac{1}{\Phi'(t)}\, dx
=\frac{2}{b-a}\, dx
\end{align*}
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align*}
||{(f\circ\Phi)}||_{L^2_{[-1,1]}}
&=\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1|f(\Phi(t))|^2\, dt}\\
&=\sqrt{\int_{\Phi(-1)=a}^{\Phi(1)=b}|f(x)|^2\frac{2}{b-a}\, dx}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{b-a}}\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^2\, dx}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{b-a}}||{f}||_{L^2_{[a,b]}}.
\end{align*}
$$

However, the solution in my book says $||{(f\circ\Phi)}||_{L^2_{[-1,1]}}=\sqrt{|b-a|}\cdot||{f}||_{L^2_{[a,b]}}$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Probably the book uses $$\lVert f\rVert_{L^2[c,d]}^2 = \frac{1}{d-c}\int_c^d \lvert f(u)\rvert^2\,du,$$ normalising the measure of the space to $1$.

Comment: Err, no. That would make composition with $\Phi$ an isometry. $$\lVert f\rVert_{L^2[c,d]} = \frac{1}{d-c}\sqrt{\int_c^d \lvert f(u)\rvert^2\,du}$$ would do it. But that's a weird normalisation.

Comment: The book defines the L^2 norm for an arbitrary interval without normalisation.

Comment: Well, take $f \equiv 1$. Without normalising factors, $\lVert 1\rVert_{L^2[c,d]} = \sqrt{d-c}$. So if there is a constant $K$ such that $\lVert f\circ \Phi\rVert_{L^2[-1,1]} = K\cdot \lVert f\rVert_{L^2[a,b]}$ for all $f\in L^2[a,b]$, then $\sqrt{2} = K\cdot \sqrt{b-a}$, so only yours has a chance to be right. (It is right, then.) So whoever wrote the solutions dun goofed. Happens all the time.